# Ng-click won't execute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-controller

I want to make my div tag clickable, but I can't get it to work.
I am working with Angular 1.5 and Ionic V1.

When an user logs in I want he/she to be presented with this view:

```
<ion-modal-view>
<ion-header-bar>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" ng-click="closeModal()"><i class="ion-chevron-left big-icon"></i></button>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <div class="modal" style="background-color: #EDEEF1;" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <div class="row row-white">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <div class="divider20"></div>
            <h4 style="margin-top:30px;">Martin Nordström</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-white">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <p style="color: #006E78; margin-bottom:40px;">990624****</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider20"></div>
        <div class="row row-white main-container">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <p style="color:#006E78;">Vart vill du ta emot dina leveranser?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box" ng-class="{'info-box-active':isActive}" ng-click="activeBtn()" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
            <div class="box-row">
                <div class="header">
                    <p class="leftText">IKANO Bostad</p>
                    <p class="rightText">Leveransrum</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box-row">
                <div class="fields">
                    <p class="leftText">Folkungagatan 100</p>
                    <p class="rightText">10 kr/månad</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box">
            <div class="box-row">
                <div class="fields mixed">
                    <p class="leftText">Lägg till en ny leveransbox</p>
                    <p class="rightText">0 kr/månad</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-white">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <button style="border-radius:50px; width:200px; height:45px;" class="button" ng-click="closeModal()">Klar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider20"></div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

That view is showing up after the user has logged in, but all the `ng-click`s are not working. Here's the controller:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, alerter, $localStorage, WizardHandler, datamapper, data, api, $state, authToken, $ionicModal, storage, endpointHandler, loadingHandler, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {
```

And inside the controller I have this function:

```
$timeout(function () {
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/deliveryDestination.modal.html', {
    scope: $scope.$scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal
    modal.show()
})
```

}, 1000)

**EDIT: Here's the implementation of the `activeBtn()`**

```
$scope.isActive = false
$scope.activeBtn = function () {
    console.log("clicked!");
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive
}
```

I am new to Angular, but with my (little) experience I think that the problem has something to do with the controller who is not connected properly. But I can be wrong! Hopefully we can solve this problem together, and I am grateful for all the support I can get.

Thanks

Comment: is there any errors in the console ?

Comment: @Abdoutelb There's no errors unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @Martin, can you please try with *(click)* instead of *ng-click*. I hope it will help.

Comment: ok can you share the implementation of `activeBtn` this the click that doesn't work ?

Comment: @AlexisToby Hey friend! Thanks for taking your time to reply, but that didn't do the trick either. :/

Comment: @MartinNordström   your controller getting called or not ?

Comment: @Abdoutelb I've added the code with the `activeBtn` in my post above. Please ask if you want more context. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Hey again @Ved. No I do not believe its being called and I think that's the issue. I just don't know how to call it.

Comment: @MartinNordström ok where did you place your `ng-app` ?

Comment: @Abdoutelb in my `index.html` file. The html code you see above is just one of many modals.

Comment: @MartinNordström try to place your controller here `<ion-content ng-controller="LoginCtrl">` and remove it from the whole page

Comment: @Abdoutelb I tried to move it here: `<ion-content ng-controller="LoginCtrl">`, but with no luck :(

Comment: @MartinNordström did your controller `LoginCtrl` is attached to you angular app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.isActive = false
$scope.activeBtn = function () {
    alert("clicked!");
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-header-bar>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" ng-click="closeModal()"><i class="ion-chevron-left big-icon"></i></button>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content ng-app="app" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <div class="modal" style="background-color: #EDEEF1;" >
        <div class="row row-white">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <div class="divider20"></div>
            <h4 style="margin-top:30px;">Martin Nordström</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-white">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <p style="color: #006E78; margin-bottom:40px;">990624****</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider20"></div>
        <div class="row row-white main-container">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <p style="color:#006E78;">Vart vill du ta emot dina leveranser?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box" ng-class="{'info-box-active':isActive}" ng-click="activeBtn()">
            <div class="box-row">
                <div class="header">
                    <p class="leftText">IKANO Bostad</p>
                    <p class="rightText">Leveransrum</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box-row">
                <div class="fields">
                    <p class="leftText">Folkungagatan 100</p>
                    <p class="rightText">10 kr/månad</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box">
            <div class="box-row">
                <div class="fields mixed">
                    <p class="leftText">Lägg till en ny leveransbox</p>
                    <p class="rightText">0 kr/månad</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-white">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <button style="border-radius:50px; width:200px; height:45px;" class="button" ng-click="closeModal()">Klar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider20"></div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I don't see problem with this,can you check and compare with your's

Comment: ahhhh! I forgot to put it in the global scope! Silly me

Comment: @MartinNordström No worries :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the **`ng-controller="LoginCtrl"`** outside all the div, otherwise $scope won't get the context.

```
 <ion-modal-view ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
```

Comment: Hello! I tried with that, but it didn't work. Thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.activeBtn = function(){
 
 alert("asdasd")
 }
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  
  <title>Angular-Google-Charts Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal" style="background-color: #EDEEF1;" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <div class="row row-white">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <div class="divider20"></div>
            <h4 style="margin-top:30px;">Martin Nordström</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-white">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <p style="color: #006E78; margin-bottom:40px;">990624****</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider20"></div>
        <div class="row row-white main-container">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <p style="color:#006E78;">Vart vill du ta emot dina leveranser?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box" style="background-color:red;" ng-click="activeBtn()">
            <div class="box-row">
                <div class="header">
                    <p class="leftText">IKANO Bostad</p>
                    <p class="rightText">Leveransrum</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box-row">
                <div class="fields">
                    <p class="leftText">Folkungagatan 100</p>
                    <p class="rightText">10 kr/månad</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box">
            <div class="box-row">
                <div class="fields mixed">
                    <p class="leftText">Lägg till en ny leveransbox</p>
                    <p class="rightText">0 kr/månad</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-white">
            <div class="col col-grey">
                <button style="border-radius:50px; width:200px; height:45px;" class="button" ng-click="closeModal()">Klar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider20"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Works perfectly fine.Just removed `ng-controller="LoginCtrl"` next to `ng-click="activeBtn"`